# impliment array.map() on an array which itself is an element of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here i have an array called `"array"` which has 4 arrays as element.As individual elements of `"array"` are also arrays itself,so i can use any array methods on them,right?So if choose the first element say `array[0].map(callback)` ,but unfortunately an error is occurring .How can i fix this problem ??

```
var array=[['apple','jackfruit'],['orange'],['pineapple'],['banana']];
(function(){
   console.log(array[0]);
     var arr=array[0].map(function(row){
         return row.reduce(function(first,second){
             return Math.max(first,second.length);
         },0);
      });
      console.log(arr);


})();
```

Comment: you cannot use reduce method inside map when using with single array, as map iterates one element in the array at a time, if you console.log(row) inside map before return , you'l get 'apple', and how reduce works only on string , instead if you use multidimensional array as just array.map, it works

Comment: What output are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess - do you search for the string in your array with the largest length?

With http://lodash.com/ you can do this:

```
var array=[['apple','jacklongfurit'],['orange'],['pineapple'],['banana']];

// Sort by string.length (reverse) and use "flatten" to make a 1-imension-array.
array = _.sortBy(_.flatten(array), function(element){ 
   return -element.length; 
});

console.log(array[0]);
```